# Парсинг сайта с помощью anglesharp

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Использую AngleSharp для парсинга сайта. Очень хорошая штука. Но возникла проблема. Вот мой код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string data = "Time = 12:00am temperature = 50";

    var Client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    Client.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    Client.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    string text = Client.UploadString(textBox1.Text, data);

    var parser = new HtmlParser();

    var document = parser.Parse(text);

    var result = document.QuerySelector("body").TextContent;

    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Текст сайта.doc", result, Encoding.UTF8);

    textBox4.Text = "Всё готово!";
}
```

Очистился весь сайт, но остались 3 проблемы. Надеюсь все решаемые:

1. Остался javascript код.
2. Здоровенные пробелы между строками в некоторых местах.
3. Присутствует меню сайта + комментарии если они например есть. Как бы их убрать?

В общем как-то так. Как можно решить эти проблемы, если можно конечно?

Comment: Используйте официальное API. Если его нет, скорее всего владельцы сайта не хотят, чтобы с их сайта собирали информацию скриптами.

Comment: @VladD вы имеете в виду считывать сайт с использованием AngleSharp? Да скорей всего не получиться. Сайт защищён скриптом от копирования до авторизации пользователя. Поэтому я выдёргиваю информацию с использованием прокси.

Comment: @VladD то есть 3 проблемы которые я описал не решаемые?

Comment: Ну раз сайт даже специально противится автоматическому съёму информации, просто не надо этого делать. Проблемы-то обойти можно, но вы при этом нарушаете правила пользования сайтом.

Comment: @VladD то есть по вашему Google Chrome тоже нарушает правила пользования сайтом? Если убрать галочку "Выполнение javascript" эта защита упадёт. Так как она выполняется как раз скриптом.

Comment: @VladD да и кстати, пусть даже не для этого сайта, а для открытых, как обойти 3 мои проблемы?

Comment: А вы посмотрите правила, там наверняка запрещено получать информацию скриптами. Если сайт хочет раздавать информацию, он обычно открывает API: специальные адреса, по которым можно получить чистую информацию, без разметки, скриптов и рекламы.